# How to return a list that contains the list filtering criteria?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am using the neo4j classic tutorial movie DB example. So in this tutorial:
https://guides.neo4j.com/intro-neo4j-exercises/05.html

A question asks for:

Retrieve all movies that Tom Cruise has acted in and the co-actors that acted in the same movie, returning the movie title and the list of co-actors that Tom Cruise worked with.

The solution is:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(p2:Person)
WHERE p.name ='Tom Cruise'
RETURN m.title as movie, collect(p2.name) AS `co-actors`
```

Now the co-actors list will contains all the co-actors. What if I want to include 'Tom Cruise' in the co-actors list and maybe just call it 'actors'?

To rephrase, the challenge I am trying to solve is:

*Retrieve all movies that Tom Cruise has acted in and all the actors that acted in the same movie, returning the movie title and the list of actors including Tom Cruise.*

Answer (score 1):

this would do it :

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(p2:Person)
WHERE p.name ='Tom Cruise' AND p <> p2
RETURN m.title as movie, [p.name] + collect(p2.name) AS `co-actors`
```

Answer (score 0):

Using reduce to accumulate the actor names and split to convert the string into a list.

```
// Find tom cruise, his movies and co-actors
MATCH (p:Person {name: 'Tom Cruise'})-[:ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(p2:Person) 
// Accumulate all actors in a string starting with tom cruise
WITH m.title as movie, reduce(coActors=p.name, p2 in collect(p2) | coActors + "," + p2.name) AS allActors
// create a list of co-actors on the accumulated coActors string
RETURN movie, split(allActors,",") AS `co-actors`

 Result:


╒════════════════╤══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"movie"         │"co-actors"                                                           │
╞════════════════╪══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│"Jerry Maguire" │["Tom Cruise","Jerry O'Connell","Bonnie Hunt","Jay Mohr","Cuba Gooding│
│                │ Jr.","Jonathan Lipnicki","Renee Zellweger","Kelly Preston","Regina Ki│
│                │ng"]                                                                  │
├────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"Top Gun"       │["Tom Cruise","Val Kilmer","Meg Ryan","Tom Skerritt","Kelly McGillis",│
│                │"Anthony Edwards"]                                                    │
├────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│"A Few Good Men"│["Tom Cruise","James Marshall","Kevin Pollak","J.T. Walsh","Aaron Sork│
│                │in","Cuba Gooding Jr.","Christopher Guest","Noah Wyle","Kiefer Sutherl│
│                │and","Kevin Bacon","Demi Moore","Jack Nicholson"]                     │
└────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

Comment: what is the benefit of using the reduce method to join and then split later?